# Using ASP Container.ItemIndex in C# if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I've been thrown a problem regarding ASP and C# without any experience in either and on a server that I have limited access to and where I can't see proper error logs. So prepare yourselves for a potentially confusing question :)

We have a loop (an ASP repeater) in a HTML template and a part of the HTML in the template should only be included in the first iteration of the loop. Unfortunately I can't just hide the html for the other iterations, I need to remove it.

So essentially want to do this:

```
<% if (Container.ItemIndex == 0) { %>
    Lots of HTML here
<% } %>
```

Problem is this produces an error (and I can't see the logs so I don't know exactly why...). I know the if statement itself works (setting 0 == 0 instead works as an example), and I can get the index normally, just not here.

So the question is, how does one do something like this? Can I access the index in the C# if statement or is there something built into the repeater that I can use?

Comment: As I said I can't see the error message since I only have limited access to the server. Makes debugging code rather interesting... also horrible.

Comment: Try to replace it with <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 %>">

Comment: I might be able to, I don't have the setup for it and was hoping to avoid going there as this is the only thing I need to do :)

Comment: Amiram - Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @ErikHonn / Amiram, Ha I didn't mean to steal the answer here. I was already going to suggest this but thought I should credit Amiram as he mentioned it first in a comment (I won't be getting any reputation from it today anyway)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than using an If statement, I would nest the "0 index only" content inside an ASP.NET `Placeholder` web control, and set `visible=true` only for the first item.

As [@Amiram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953420/using-asp-container-itemindex-in-c-sharp-if-statement/11956444#comment15927607_11953420) has stated, you could do:

```
<asp:Placeholder id="ph" runat="server" visible="<%# (bool)(Container.ItemIndex==0) %>">
    ...0 Index only content
</asp:Placeholder>
```

Alternatively, set `visible="false"` and change this value in the `ItemDataBound` event:

```
if (e.Item.ItemIndex == 0){
   (placeholder)e.Item.FindControl("ph").visible = true;
}
```